# Modify Clojure source code file in clojure

Tags: file-io, clojure

I was wondering if it's possible to load the code contained in a Clojure `.clj` source file as a list, without compiling it.

If I can load a `.clj` file as a list, I can modify that list and pretty print it back into the same file which can then be loaded again.

(Maybe this is a bad idea.) Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: It's not a bad idea at all.  It can be used for things like code analysis and rfactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly simpler example:

```
user=> (def a '(println (+ 1 1))) ; "'" escapes the form to prevent immediate evaluation
#'user/a
user=> (spit "test.code" a) ; write it to a file
nil

user=> (def from-file (read-string (slurp "test.code"))) ; read it from a file
#'user/from-file
user=> (def modified (clojure.walk/postwalk-replace {1 2} from-file)) ; modify the code
#'user/modified
user=> (spit "new.code" modified) ; write it back
nil
user=> (load-string (slurp "new.code")) ; check it worked!
4
nil
```

Where `slurp` gives you a string, `read-string` gives you an un-evaluated form, and `load-string` gives you the result of evaluating the form.

Answer (score 7):

It is not a bad idea, it is one of the major properties of lisp, code is data.
you can read the clj file as a list using read-string modify it and write it back.

```
(ns tmp
  (:require [clojure.zip :as zip])
  (:use clojure.contrib.pprint))

(def some-var true)

;;stolen from http://nakkaya.com/2011/06/29/ferret-an-experimental-clojure-compiler/
(defn morph-form [tree pred f]
  (loop [loc (zip/seq-zip tree)]
    (if (zip/end? loc)
      (zip/root loc)
      (recur
       (zip/next
        (if (pred (zip/node loc))
          (zip/replace loc (f (zip/node loc)))
          loc))))))

(let [morphed (morph-form (read-string (str \( (slurp "test.clj")\)))
                          #(or (= 'true %)
                               (= 'false %))
                          (fn [v] (if (= 'true v)
                                   'false
                                   'true)))]
  (spit "test.clj"
        (with-out-str
          (doseq [f morphed]
            (pprint f)))))
```

This reads itself and toggles boolean values and writes it back.

Comment: Adding parens around the slurped text is not a good idea. Using `read` repeatedly until the file is consumed is cleaner and more robust.

Comment: Cool! I'm gonna try this! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called **rewrite-clj** which can this type of thing.

https://github.com/xsc/rewrite-clj

Answer (score 0):

Without any libraries, what you'd like to do is

```
(with-open [reader (java.io.PushbackReader. 
                     (clojure.java.io/reader "src/my/file/ns_path.clj"))]
  (loop [forms []]
    (try 
      (recur (conj forms (read reader)))
      (catch Exception ex
        (println (.getMessage ex))
        forms))))
```

but Clojure doesn't allow `recur` across `try`, so instead you do

```
(with-open [reader (java.io.PushbackReader. 
                     (clojure.java.io/reader "src/my/file/ns_path.clj"))]
  (loop [[ forms done? ] 
         [ []    false ]]
    (if done?
      forms
      (recur (try
               [(conj forms (read reader)) false]
               (catch Exception ex
                 (println (.getMessage ex))
                 [forms true]))))))
```

You need to propagate the `done?` signal yourself once reading is complete upon the EOF (end-of-file) error. I tried to layout the `loop` bindings so they match up clearly top to bottom.

That will return a vector of all the forms in the file. From there, you can perform whatever transformations you want on the forms as data, and spit/print/write them back to the file again.

**REQUISITE LEGAL DISCLAIMER REGARDING `read`**

Don't run `clojure.core/read` on code/data you didn't write or check yourself first. See [this ClojureDocs comment](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/read#example-542692d5c026201cdc327056) for examples of what can go wrong.